# Dynamic IIS Compression Module and Vary: Accept-Encoding Header is not overwritten

Tags: asp.net-mvc, header, compression, vary

When you enable dynamic content compression on a computer that is running Windows Server 2008, a Vary header is always overwritten as "Accept-Encoding.". You cannot change it by code.

This hotfix http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2877816 resolves the issue for serveral versions but it doesn't apply to Windows Server 2008.

Is there another hotfix for Windows Server 2008?